# Sublime text 2 Search and replace with random number

Tags: regex, ide, sublimetext2, sublimetext

is it possible to search and replace a text string with a random number e.g.

`Search: "This is the number 23 and i like it"`

`replace: "this is the number " . Rand(0,100) . " and i like it"`

is that possible?

Comment: What about you use something like this for a replacement `this is the number 4 and I like it` [xkcd](http://xkcd.com/221/) ? But seriously ST uses the [Boost syntax](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/libs/regex/doc/html/boost_regex/syntax/perl_syntax.html), I don't think that's possible since you will need a callback. So you may [create your own plugin](http://www.sublimetext.com/docs/plugin-basics) that does exactly this for you. Another not so random way would be to match certain digits and put them in a separate group `(\d)(\d)(\d*)` and in the replace you just swap them `$2$1$3`.

Answer (score 3):

Not out of the box, but if you are familiar with Python, you could easily create a plugin to do so.

Comment: This would be the way to accomplish this. A regex search could _locate_ the string you want to modify, but it can't _generate_ a random number to use in the replacement. This would have to be done with a [plugin](http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/extensibility/plugins.html).